# How do you position and set different elements of toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

> I want to create a toolbar shown in this image.

[image]

> how do we do that?

i have done this:

```
 Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

so far.

Comment: You can use a relative or linear layout designed like that. Toolbar is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

create custome toolbar by this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@mipmap/top_bar_bg"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

put this in activity

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

put this in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            >
```

replace your current activity with `android:name` and replace your parent activity with `android:parentActivity`

For menu: create menu resource file and add items init like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.parsaniahardik.tabwithmaterial.SimpleTabsActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_account"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="account"

        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />



</menu>
```

put this in activity for menu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        if(id == R.id.action_settings){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override onCreateOptionsMenu, as such:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout_name, menu);
}
```

where menu_layout_name is the name of the menu layout. This menu_layout_name is as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_item"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>
</item>
```